# Asymptotic behavior of $_3F_2$ at unit argument for large values of parameters

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

I have to deal a lot with functions which are $_3F_2$ with unit argument, and I need to find their behavior for large values of the parameters.
One example is

$$_3F_2(n,n,n;2n,n+x;1)$$

where I'm interested in the behavior of large $n$. Now, I have played around with this function numerically a bit and it looks to me that asymptotically (for $n \to \infty$) it behaves as

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}4^n n^{1/2-x} \Gamma(x)$$

However, this is of course very dirty and I would like to have a clean way to get this kind of asymptotics. Is there a way to do this or are there some references with similar results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is correct if $\pi$ is changed to $\sqrt \pi$. For this particular example, we have
$${_3\hspace{-1px}F_2}(n, n, n; 2 n, n + x; 1) =
\frac {\Gamma(x) \Gamma(2 n)} {\Gamma(n) \Gamma(n + x)}
 \,{_3\hspace{-1px}F_2}(n, x, x; n + x, n + x; 1).$$
Now the $k$th term in the hypergeometric sum is of order $n^{-k}$. For $n \to \infty$ and $x$ fixed,
$${_3\hspace{-1px}F_2}(n, x, x; n + x, n + x; 1) \sim 1, \\
\frac {\Gamma(x) \Gamma(2 n)} {\Gamma(n) \Gamma(n + x)} \sim
\frac {\Gamma(x) n^{1/2 - x} 2^{2 n - 1}} {\sqrt \pi}.$$

Comment: yes the missing square root was a typo. Thanks a lot!